# Text not being encoded in text file

Tags: java, file, encoding

The following program attempts to encode text passed as parameters to the writeUTF() function and store it in a text file:

```
import java.io.*;
class Output2{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Bluej\\Files\\bOutput2i.txt");
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
        //dos.writeUTF("Hello there");
        
        //dos.writeUTF("Hello hi");
        
        dos.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("File ended");
    }
}
```

Uncommenting `dos.writeUTF("Hello hi")` stores

> ࠀ效汬⁯楨

in the bOutput2i.txt file. That is, the text is encoded in the file.

However, if I uncomment `dos.writeUTF("Hello there")` instead, the bOutput2i.txt file stores

> Hello there

That is, the text is not encoded in the file.

How does this difference in encoding arise by simply changing the text to be encoded and how can this problem be resolved?

Comment: is there any reason why you're using *Modified UTF-8*?

Comment: You didn't say, but I bet you are running on Windows. [There is a long-known bug on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) which incorrectly interprets certain data patterns as UTF-16, which turns them into gibberish. Try looking at the file with a pre-Unicode function, like `type` in a CMD window.

Comment: I think you are expecting something that isn't what you are actually doing. You are using a `DataOutputStream`. But you read it as if it was a text file. It isn't. It's a binary file. `writeUTF` first writes two bytes which are the string's length - which isn't done in a text file.

Comment: Do not use DataOutputStream to write a text file.  Use an OutputStreamWriter, or use `Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of("D:\\Bluej\\Files\\bOutput2i.txt"))`.